# VGA for external monitor is flickering

Tags: 10.10, xorg, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GMA 5700 MHD Dell Vostro 3300 externel vga monitor is flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7700/gma-5700-mhd-dell-vostro-3300-externel-vga-monitor-is-flickering)

I use the Dell Vostro 3300 und Ubuntu Lucid 10.10. The problem was on 10.04.1 too.

The VGA for the external monitor is flickering. The problem seams to be the Intel GMA X4500HD .

So, do you know 1.) what i can do? or 2.) where i can find a Driver for the Intel GMA
X4500HD - maybe a deb package, because I am a absolute beginner.