# GMA 5700 MHD Dell Vostro 3300 externel vga monitor is flickering

Tags: 10.10, intel-graphics, dell

I use the Dell Vostro 3300 und Ubuntu Lucid 10.10. The VGA for the external monitor is flickering. The problem seams to be the Intel Graphics.

lspci / grep “VGA” says: VGA compatible controler: Intel Corporation Core Prozessor Integrated Graphics Controler (rev 18)

Dell told me on the telephone it is the GMA 5700MHD

Has somebody an idea, what i can do?

Comment: Sorry, i am an absolut beginner:
if i type  sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-2.6.38-997_2.6.38-997.201102120912_all.deb

then I get the error message " can t find the file..."

Comment: Running meerkat amd64 on my 3300, installed the three respective packages from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-next/2011-02-23-natty/ Rebooted into new kernel but still no joy, external monitor flickering as before. Sad times

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to look for an Intel driver around, because it is shipped with Ubuntu and installed by default.

There is a bug with the Intel driver and the card you're mentioning (I have the same card), however most reporter have it with their laptop LCD, not the external screen. I also have no problem with external screens...

Anyway, there is a workaround for this bug that works for the LCD internal screen of the laptop, perhaps it is working also for an external LCD, you could give it a try.

Check the following bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/538648

The workaround concerns adding `i915.powersave=0` to the kernel parameters, see the [workaround] section in the bug description.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not working :( If this would be the problem the mistake would not be in 10.10.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the GMA X4500HD ???

Comment: Sorry, it is the GMA x4500MHD

Comment: I have the GM45 chipset, which according to Intel is a GMA 4500MHD so I have the mobile version, and you have the desktop version of the graphical chipset.

Comment: Shiz, i just phoned Dell. They told me, that it is an GMA 5700MHD so, i dont know what to do :-(

Answer (score 0):

Follow this bug :
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28306

and this :
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21742

and finally this :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/614238

Answer (score 0):

Patch has been found just few days ago @ https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28306
But, what people like me should do? I don't know - and don't want - to recompile kernel

I prefer wait the official bugfixing

Since this machine has been certified to be used with 10.04, it is reasonable to expect this issue solved in a short time?

Answer (score 0):

Install the kernel drm-intel-next available here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-next/2011-02-12-natty/

It works, I have the same model of notebook and I solved with:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-2.6.38-997_2.6.38-997.201102120912_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-2.6.38-997-generic_2.6.38-997.201102120912_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-2.6.38-997-generic_2.6.38-997.201102120912_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

DELL Vostro 3300 Proven!

For AMD:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-2.6.38-997_2.6.38-997.201102120912_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-2.6.38-997-generic_2.6.38-997.201102120912_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-2.6.38-997-generic_2.6.38-997.201102120912_amd64.deb
```

For Intel:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-2.6.38-997_2.6.38-997.201102120912_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-2.6.38-997-generic_2.6.38-997.201102120912_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-2.6.38-997-generic_2.6.38-997.201102120912_i386.deb
```